# Why am I getting an IllegalArgumentException with this code to create an image?

Tags: java-me

I wrote this code for my j2me project:

```
try {
    Image immutableThumb = Image.createImage(temp, 0, temp.length);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Where `temp` is a byte array.

When I tried it for localhost it works, and the image gets created.
But when I tried it on LAN it throws an `IllegalArgumentException`, and the image is not created.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you passing is a byte array from a string of a network location, or are you loading the byte array over a network?

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Image.html) say

> IllegalArgumentException - if imageData is incorrectly formatted or otherwise cannot be decoded

so I'd say you're getting a different byte array.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the byte array from a network location, be sure it came from a supported image type. I mean, not every image format is available on MIDP. To be sure, you can use PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Is it on device or in emulator that you are having a problem? It could be the url string, or a problem with the connection.

Can you post all your source code?

Here's a simple example: [how to download an image from a web-server.](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-download-an-image-from-a-web-server-3.html)